# gzip_http_version 1.1; in Nginx, when using HTTP/2

Tags: server, nginx, https

In an Nginx server block of a site aimed to work with HTTP/2, I've seen this:

```
gzip_http_version 1.1;
```

Can this make some conflict with some packets sent in HTTP/2?

I don't understand this Gzip directive hence I can't say if HTTP/2 packets could be affected by it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`gzip_http_version`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html) is the *minimum* version of the HTTP protocol of the *request* (coming from client) needed to compress the response from server. It defaults to `1.1`.

So, any user agent that is sending request using protocol version 1.0, won't get the response compressed from server; the response would go as-is. Note that, setting the value to 1.1 would probably hurt very very tiny subset of crowd (probably someone with Win XP, which is unsupported now BTW), if any.

To answer your question:

> Can this make some conflict with some packets sent in HTTP/2?

No, as `nginx` would handle requests differently based on the value of `$server_protocol` variable (one of `HTTP/1.0`, `HTTP/1.1`, `HTTP/2.0`).

---

As a side note, as `Transfer-Encoding` header is not supported in `HTTP/1.0` you should not set `gzip_http_version` to `1.0`. Otherwise, you would not get keepalives as `Content-Length` header is not set when `gzip_http_version` is used; HTTP/1.1 tackles this using `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header.